# MySQL Alter Table Memory Increase

Tags: c#, mysql, memory-management, alter

I'm trying to alter 2000 tables by adding a column to each. I achieve this by using a for loop in C# and executing a query on each table name for a list of strings I have. It starts out fast but then gets slower and slower. The memory for mysql.exe increases from 50k to 375k in about 30 seconds. Why is it doing this? Once I do one alter table the memory should drop down again. Is some resource not being disposed of after each alter? A cache, or buffer? Garbage collection? I can't finish this for loop because it gets incredible slow after the 20th-25th alter table.

Comment: Upvote because your question stopped me from writing some code to do the exact same thing in the exact same way. So thanks! :-)

Comment: Why do you have 2000 tables? And is 50k to 375k correct? I mean .... It is quite rare to see database software using less than 1MB of memory these days. A pretty average machine could run close to 10.000 instances of 375KB programs. Is that correct?

Comment: It's for a minecraft server. Each level has a table associated with it. The memory starts at 50k in the task manager (WINDOWS 7) and increases to 375k as I perform the script.

Comment: are tables innodb or myisam ?

Comment: Innodb. I'm just going to tough it out and let it run for a long time. So far the script has been running over an hour. It's weird. It will add like 20 tables in 10 seconds. Then take a break for like 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you issue a `alter table` statement to MySQL, it starts rebuilding the table.

It does the following steps:

1. Copy the `old` table to a new file.
2. Add a column to the `new` file definition .frm-file
3. Add the column in the datafile in the `new` .myd-datafile, this requires rewriting the entire datafile.
4. Go through all the rows in the `new` datafile to fill the new column with the default value
5. If the new column has an index MySQL has to do steps 2,3,4 for the .MYI-indexfile as well.
6. Rename the `old` datafile
7. Rename the `new` datafile so it has the same name the `old` file had.
8. Delete the `old` datafile

For performance reasons it will try to keep the `new` data and index file in memory.
This is the memory increase you are seeing.
MySQL will keep the table data in memory for some time and will only clear out the cache if the memory assigned to cache space in `My.ini` has been exhausted.

You can clear the cache by issuing:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

After every `alter table` statement.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html
Read up on MySQL cache issues here: http://www.docplanet.org/mysql/mysql-query-cache-in-depth/

Comment: I added the reset query cache after each ALTER and the memory is still increasing. It also said 0 rows affected.

Comment: @MattM, A memory increase from 50k to 375k is tiny, so **that** will not cause any slowness, how much memory are we really talking about here?

Comment: The memory is maxing out at 354,568K. But now my alter table statements are going extremely slow. Like 7 every minute.